# Why does my ModelState.AddModelError shows error in my index method?

Tags: c#, modelstate

I am new to C# and I encounter this error while doing my code in the 
[HomeController.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKJ56.png)

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string searchString)
    {
        QnAQuery objQnAResult = new QnAQuery();
        try
        {
            if (searchString != null)
            {
                objQnAResult = await QueryQnABot(searchString);
            }
            return View(objQnAResult);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Error: " + ex);
            return View(objQnAResult);
        }
    }
```

And when I tried to build the code, there are errors shown in the link.
And it says that **The name "ModelState" does not exist in the context**.
And **The name "View" does not exist in the context**.

What could be the possible reason for having such problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Please paste your code and errors in the question

Comment: @EvanHuang I just copied the code in my HomeController

Comment: The `ModelState` and `View` are defined in the `Controller` class, please confirm if your `HomeController` inherited from the `Controller` class

Comment: Yes, it doesn't show error at all. Thanks!